# How do I get "ls -l" to show me group names instead of numbers (git bash)

Tags: bash

When I use the `ls -l` command in `git bash`, the group column always shows a number:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 JoelFan 5235961   8774 Aug 13  2021 README.md
```

How can I get it to show a meaningful name instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\nsswitch.conf` and change the line:

```
group: files # db
```

to:

```
group: files db
```

This will allow cause the system to check both the `/etc/group` file ("**files**") and the underlying Windows filesystem ("**db**") for group information.  (In the original version, the "**db**" option is commented out, so the operating system is not checked)

Then you will get output from `ls -l` like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 JoelFan Domain Users  8774 Aug 13  2021 README.md
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/NSS-Configuration-File.html

**NOTE:** The default of commenting out "**db**" may be to optimize performance.  If you experience unacceptable performance issues after changing this, you may want to change it back.